# Include JavaScript files from a control if the files have not been included before

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have written a control requires certain JavaScript files to run, like
jquery-1.5.1.min.js
jquery.colorbox.js
and another custom file, lets call it gallery.js

I'm thinking about how I can make the control more reusable on different content pages, without the need to load the scripts on pagelevel with the ScriptManagerProxy, meaning that I don't need to do this on every content page:

```
<asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="proxy1" runat="server">
   <Scripts>
     <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" />
     <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/scripts/jquery.colorbox.js" />
     <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/scripts/gallery.js" />
   </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
```

That implementation has one disadvantage. If I want to use the control on another page, I'd have to think about the scripts being required. I would rather use an implementation where the control itself loads the necessary JavaScript files, without loading certain scripts more then once.
Let's assume I use my control three times on the same page, so I don't want to end up loading all the JavaScript files three times. What can I do?

I'm looking for a solution like this:

```
if(Page.Scripts["path to javascript file"] == null)
{
 Page.Scripts.InsertJavaScript("path to javascript file");
}
```

How can I proceed in this situation? (I don't want to load the scripts on a pagelevel or in a masterpage to produce unnecessary overhead)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [RegisterClientScriptInclude](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerclientscriptinclude.aspx):

```
if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered(typeof(MyControl), "someName")) {
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(typeof(MyControl), "someName", ResolveUrl("./something.js"));
}
```

Comment: I guess typeof(MyControl) would result in loading the script files twice, if they are also present in the ScriptManager?

Comment: @citronas: There is also an overload of the method without type, maybe you could use that.

Comment: Ok the overload works fine as well for registering. I still have the problem, that if I use a ScriptReference in a ScriptManager or a ScriptManagerProxy, the scripts will be included twice. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use the ClientScript.RegisterXYZ methods which take a Type and a Key. ASP.Net will only output each unique script once.

Answer (score 0):

I belive you can do something like this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this, this.GetType(), "scriptName", "the script url);
```

This will register the include script only once. It uses the scriptName to register it and it does not register it twice.

Comment: Will be script be loaded twice, If I already included it via the ScriptManager or ScriptManagerProxy?